# ArcGIS Focal Statistics Returns Out-of-Bounds Result

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, focal-statistics

I am trying to compute a moving window maximum on a raster, such that the output is the max within a 5 mile radius.
This should result in an output grid where the maximum is equal to the maximum of the input grid.
I am using the FocalStatistics function in spatial analyst,

Here is the code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.extent = "MAXOF"
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

localMax = FocalStatistics(InRaster, NbrCircle(5, "MAP"), "MAXIMUM")
```

Pretty straight forward.
But if I check that stats:
    arcpy.GetRasterProperties(localMax, “MAXIMUM”)
The value returned is 3.4e+38 (out to lunch), whereas:

```
arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster, “MAXIMUM”)
```

returns 5.73

I have used this function without problems before – I am out of ideas. Anyone?

edit: inRaster is projected, and the linear unit is Miles (US)

Comment: Ignore NoData can play tricks

Comment: Felix - Good point, I tried with the ignore NoData parameter set to True, and then False. I got the same result! Am I applying this correctly?
    localMax = FocalStatistics(InRaster, NbrCircle(5, "MAP"), "MAXIMUM", True)

Comment: Further testing, tried both "DATA" and "NODATA" in the ignore NoData parameter. Same result

Comment: If this is standalone script, "MAP" parameter might not work, try CELL

Comment: No luck with "CELL" either. I tried both "DATA" and "NODATA" with it as well. Fixed my GetRasterProperies_management in the question. Thanks Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly fine

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
inRaster=arcpy.Raster(r'D:\Aerials\Backups\arc2mdem')
localMax = FocalStatistics(inRaster, NbrCircle(5, "MAP"), "MAXIMUM")
result=arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(localMax, "MAXIMUM")
arcpy.AddMessage(result.getOutput(0))
```

The only other thing I can think of is environment extent. Does baaad things very often.

UPDATE:
tested with wrong extent, get the same "answer" 3.40282e+038

Comment: Felix - What do you mean "wrong extent?" I set env.extent() before running the script, and the projection is the same for inRaster as the extent raster. Is there something else?

Comment: Set it inside the script env.extent=raster.extent or union of inputs

Comment: It sounds like this is the problem, but I am not able to correct. I have tried setting arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF", and not setting the extent explicitly, like you show in your script above.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
This issue seems to be related to floats. If the input raster is multiplied by 1.0 before running the focal statistics, it yields the expected results.